# Condition for related table ORM Kohana

Tags: php, orm, kohana

For example I have 3 tables:

```
songs(id, song_name)
song_category(id, song_id, category_id)
categories(id, name)
```

I want to get songs which have categories with id higher than 5. I want to do it using ORM, not with simple SQL query. Is it possible to do it with one query like this:

```
$songs = ORM::factory("songs")->where("category.id > 5")
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do this with a single Kohana ORM call.

The best way I have found to do it is something like this, which makes a modification to the SQL query that the ORM will generate:

```
// Get the basic "song" model
$songs = ORM::factory("songs");

// Get the information about how it is connected to
// the "category" model using the `through` model
$song_relations = $results->has_many();
$category_relation = $song_relations['categories'];
$through = $category_relation['through'];

// Join on `through` model's target foreign key (far_key) and `target` model's primary key
$join_col1 = $through.'.'.$category_relation['foreign_key'];
$join_col2 = $songs->object_name().'.'.$songs->primary_key();
$songs->join($through)->on($join_col1, '=', $join_col2);

// Now, filter on the 
$songs->where($through.'.'.$category_relation['far_key'], '>', 5);

$arr = $results->find_all()->as_array();
```

You could save some code by hardcoding the values in the `join` method call, but this way leverages the ORM relation definitions that you already have.

This assumes that your `Song` model has the following code in it:

```
protected $_has_many = [
    'categories' => [
        'model'       => 'category',
        'through'     => 'song_category',
        'foreign_key' => 'song_id',
        'far_key'     => 'category_id',
    ]
];
```